# How to set up a Obsidian banner compatible with Gitbook deploy

Tags: markdown, gitbook, obsidian

I have a continuous deployment webpage on Gitbook that takes its content from my Github repository where I upload my personal notes written in Obsidian in Markdown.
So I found an Obsidian plugin (Banners) that inserts banners like Notion does, and in Obsidian works perfectly, but when I see the note on the page, the banner doesn't appear.
The format of the banner is like this:

```
---
banner: "![[./img/banner.jpg]]"
---
```

I've tried to set it up like a normal md image but it doesn't extend to the margins of the note, so it is not a banner (it's more like a normal photo)

So what I want is to see that image as notion banners but in gitbook.

Comment: I want to learn more about this workflow. Do you have any notes/webpages where I can replicate what you are doing?

Comment: I do not have notes, but by deeping in I discovered that gitbook creates hidden folder called `.gitbook` and inside it creates a folder called `assets`, where the banners are stored. Hope it can serve you!

Comment: You can check my repository if it serves you: https://github.com/gitblanc/Obsidian-Notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that in my case works, so the inserted banner may look like this:

```
---
banner: "![[path/to/your/banner.jpg]]"
cover: .gitbook/assets/banner.jpg
coverY: 0
---
```

So the main thing is that gitbook uses a hidden folder with assets, and inside there you must put the banner for being recognized.